# Convert from Text to Columns in Excel

Tags: excel, notepad

I have following input in text format:
|Number|Name|SUMinRUB|Reason
|-|Table|1000|This is Text
| | | |Splitted in
| | | |Seveal Lines
|2|Chairs|2000|This is another
| | | |Text splitted
| | | |In several lines

And when converting to Excel, Reason column is converted into several lines. I need, to make it like this:
[Result in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43SX1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must replace `"||||"` to `""` (empty string) or `" "` (space) (Find&Select -> Replace) in whole file before using the TextToColumns function.